# Exporting multiple sizes in sketch. Saving it as defaults?

Tags: export, sketch-app, mobile, plugin

I'm trying to figure out the way to keep my export sizes and prefix names as default options,

When I do it to mobile I have to create **7 diferents sizes and prefixe**s

**I design in @3x** so I have to export then for iOS and Android like:
[image: Sketch exporting layer properties]

So every time I create a new doc, I'm repeating this process like 20 times per day.

Let me know if you know how to perform this easier.

Note: I also tried some export plugins for mobile, but those all export my buttons without the transparent background. I mean, they add the background on it ( I can't export only the button with transparent bg)

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Maybe there are exporting scripts for sketch that do what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I programmed a script for doing this. It's pretty simple:

1 - Select a layer and then,( CMD + Shift + A ) and automatically generates this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/trpdg.png]

So you can export the layers really fast.

This is the code inside the .sketchplugin file I created (Copy and Paste it into a empty textFile and save it like exportPlugin.sketchplugin

Here is the code-->

> // (shift cmd a)
>   if (selection.length() > 0){
>
> for (var i=0; i < selection.length(); i++){ 
>         addExportSizes(selection[i])
>     }
>     [doc showMessage:"Export Options Added"]
>   }else{ 
>     var app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
>      [app displayDialog:"Anything selected :(" withTitle:"Exportabler"];
>   }
>   function addExportSizes(layer){ 
>         var iOSExportData = [
>           {
>             "format": "png",
>             "scale": 1/3,
>             "suffix": ""
>           },
>           {
>             "format": "png",
>             "scale": 2/3,
>             "suffix": "@2x"
>           },
>           {
>             "format": "png",
>             "scale": 3/3,
>             "suffix": "@3x"
>           },
>          {
>             "format": "png",
>             "scale": 1/3,
>             "suffix": "mdpi"
>           },
>           {
>             "format": "png",
>             "scale": 1/2,
>             "suffix": "hdpi"
>           },
>         {
>             "format": "png",
>             "scale": 2/3,
>             "suffix": "xhdpi"
>           },
>           {
>             "format": "png",
>             "scale": 3/3,
>             "suffix": "xxhdpi"
>           }
>         ]
>         var export_options = [layer exportOptions]
>         var export_sizes = [export_options sizes]
>         while([export_sizes count] > 0) {
>           [[export_sizes firstObject] remove]
>         }
>         for (var i = 0; i < iOSExportData.length; i++) {
>           var size_data = iOSExportData[i]
>           var size = [[layer exportOptions] addExportSize]
>           [size setFormat:size_data.format]
>           [size setScale:size_data.scale]
>           [size setName:size_data.suffix]
>         }
>         [[doc currentPage] deselectAllLayers]
>         [layer select:true byExpandingSelection:true]
>   }

Comment: This script didn't work for me... Is this still working for you in the current version of Sketch?

Comment: No.. Not any more :(